# Find coordinate of end point of a line?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

[image]

How do I find the coordinates of the endpoint of a line with its length, starting position and angle relative to the x-axis? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from the endpoint to the horizontal and use trigonometry.

Comment: Ah thank you! so the X will be cos(angle)*length+startingX and the Y will be sin(angle)*length+startingY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the unknown points $(x_1,y_1)$

The known point is (x,y)

Since we know the length of the line, let's call it $l$
$$\sin \theta= \frac{x_1-x}{l}$$
$$\cos \theta= \frac{y_1-y}{l}$$
$$x_1=l\sin \theta+x$$
$$y_1=l\cos \theta+y$$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present another (but equivalent) approach using vectors.
I hope this answer contains additional educational value.

To obtain coordinates $(x',\, y')$ out of given point $(x,\, y)$, length $\ell$, and angle $\alpha$, one can add vector $\vec \ell = (\ell\cos \alpha, \,\ell\sin \alpha)$ of length $\ell$ directed in $\alpha$ to point $(x,\, y)$:

$$
(x',\, y') = (\ell \cos \alpha, \,\ell \sin\alpha) + (x,\, y) = (x + \ell \cos\alpha, \, y + \ell \sin \alpha).
$$